# Twisted / perform asynchronous http requests

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-2.7, twisted

I have a twisted reactor listening for incoming data. I have a second reactor performing http requests in certain time intervals sending the results to the first reactor. Both run fine.

Now I would like to bring it together to run in one reactor, but I do not know how to achieve this. Something like - perform http requests every 60 sec. in an asynchrounous way from within the first listening "main" reactor.

What I have at the moment is:

```
# main reactor listening for incoming data forever
...
reactor.listenTCP(8123, TCPEventReceiverFactory())
```

The http reactor uses `twisted.internet.defer.DeferredSemaphore()` to perform several http checks:

```
# create semaphore to manage the deferreds
semaphore = twisted.internet.defer.DeferredSemaphore(2)

# create a list with all urls to check
dl = list()
# append deferreds to list
for url in self._urls:
    # returns deferred
    dl.append(semaphore.run(self._getPage, url))

# get a DefferedList
dl = twisted.internet.defer.DeferredList(dl)
# add some callbacks for error handling
dl.addCallbacks(lambda x: reactor.stop(), self._handleError)

# start the reactor    
reactor.run()
```

How can I add the timed http checks to the "main" reactor, so that they get performed in an asynchronous way? How does `DeferredSemaphore` exactly work?

Can anyone help me with this?

[This is a kind of lightweight monitoring system processing http checkresults. I am new to Twisted and asynchronous programming. I am on Xubuntu 12.04 running Python 2.7]

Comment: what is the deferred semaphore even for?

Comment: It's for limiting the requests performed simultaneously.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you don't need multiple reactors.  Just perform all of the different actions using the same reactor.

if you're calling `reactor.stop()`, you're likely doing something wrong, so lets get rid of that, and tie it all up into a single function (that we could use as a callback); since it is doing asynchronous work, it should also return a deferred, we'll use the `DeferredList` you're already using.

```
def thing_that_does_http():
    # create semaphore to manage the deferreds
    semaphore = twisted.internet.defer.DeferredSemaphore(2)

    # create a list with all urls to check
    dl = DeferredList()
    # append deferreds to list
    for url in self._urls:
        # returns deferred
        dl.append(semaphore.run(self._getPage, url))

    # get a DefferedList
    dl = twisted.internet.defer.DeferredList(dl)
    # add some callbacks for error handling
    dl.addErrback(self._handleError)
    return dl
```

The natural way to "perform *x* in certain time intervals" is with looping call.  With this callback function we don't need to do much

```
reactor.listenTCP(8123, TCPEventReceiverFactory())
loop_http = twisted.intertnet.task.LoopingCall(thing_that_does_http)
# run once per minute, starting now.
loop_http.start(60)
```

---

The reactor `LoopingCall` and `getPage` will use to for their own purposes is `twisted.internet.reactor`,  if you are using a different reactor, For instance if you are doing unit testing, you'll need to override that default.

In the case of `LoopingCall`, it's quite simple, after construction, (but *before* calling its `start()` method), set its [`clock`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.task.LoopingCall.html#clock) attribute:

```
from twisted.internet.task import Clock
fake_reactor = Clock()
loop_http.clock = fake_reactor
fake_reactor.advance(120)  # move time forward two minutes...
```

Unfortunately, the situation with `getPage()` is less nice.  You cannot use any other reactor with that interface;  You'll need to use the newer, shinier [`t.w.c.Agent`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.client.Agent.html).  In many ways `Agent` is superior, but it's not quite as convenient when you just want the raw response body as a string.

Aside from requiring an explicit reactor passed to its constructor, it's more about fine grained control over the request/response cycle than the convenience provided by getPage.  As such it's implemented mostly in terms of [`Producer`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.iweb.IBodyProducer.html)s and [`Protocol`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IProtocol.html)s.  In the case of the former, we can pass a convenience helper, [`FileBodyProducer`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.client.FileBodyProducer.html) to send request bodies with minimal fuss; in the latter, we'll need a simple protocol to buffer all of the chunks of data until we've gotten all of it.

Here's a chunk of code that could replace `getPage`, with roughly the same interface, but taking an instance of `Agent` as first argument

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol
from twisted.web.client import ResponseDone
from twisted.web.client import FileBodyProducer


class GetPageProtocol(Protocol):
    def __init__(self):
        self.deferred = Deferred()
        self.data = []

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.data.append(data)

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        reason.trap(ResponseDone)
        data = ''.join(self.data)
        del self.data
        self.deferred.callback(data)


def agentGetPage(agent, url,
                 method="GET",
                 headers=None,
                 postdata=None):
    if postdata is not None:
        bodyProducer = FileBodyProducer(StringIO(postdata))
    else:
        bodyProducer = None

    def _getPageResponded(response):
        if response.length != 0:
            proto = GetPageProtocol()
            response.deliverBody(proto)
            return proto.deferred
        else:
            return None

    d = agent.request(method, url, headers, bodyProducer)
    d.addCallback(_getPageResponded)
    return d
```

which, in a unit test, would look sort of like:

```
from twisted.test.proto_helpers import MemoryReactor
from twisted.web.client import Agent
fake_reactor = MemoryReactor()
agent = Agent(fake_reactor)
d = agentGetPage(agent, "http://example.com")

assert fake_reactor.tcpClients  # or some such, exercise the code by manipulating the reactor
```

<sub>Edit: I initially wanted to skim over this to give [ectomorph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1698398/ectomorph), less to be confused about; but then it's also a pretty good idea to drum in the proper handling of reactors early, and avoid needless pain later.</sub>

Comment: Thanks! Awesome, that is exactly what I was looking for. `twisted.internet.reactor` is the reactor I am using.

Comment: Good answer, but not entirely correct :).  `LoopingCall` will actually use `self.clock`, which is just initialized to `twisted.internet.reactor` *by default*.  The ability to change it is important, especially for testing.  (Sadly, `getPage` is effectively hard-coded to it, which is one reason why we recommend `twisted.web.client.Agent` now instead.)

Comment: @Glyph: Updated: There, I think that covers using reactor's less suckishly.

Comment: Thank you guys for the completion!

Comment: @TokenMacGuy thanks for cleaning up the answer for posterity!  If you're feeling *even more* generously inclined, there's actually a ticket to add a function like `agentGetPage` to Twisted itself, to bridge this convenience gap.  Any chance you're interested in working on it?  https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/5405